# (removing duplicates) add one of the book copies into my string

Tags: python

```
    def search(self, string):
        result = ""
        if len(string) >= 4:
            for book in self.collection:
                if (string.lower() in book.get_title().lower):
                    result += str(book)
            return result
```

I have a library class which has library.collection as a list of book objects, now I want to search the "string" and return the book I want, above are my code.
the book class has method get_title() which returns the "title" of the book adn str(book) returns a string"book id: book title"

this works well, for example when I search "under"
i got

```
    10: Under the Net
    11: Under the Net
    117: Under the Skin
```

but I have two copies of the book "under the net"

I just want to find one of them, so for every string I search, if there are several copies of a book, I just want to add one of the str(book) to my result.
can anyone help me with this?

Comment: the above code is unclear: `book_title` and `search_result` are undefined

Comment: Briefly: you should use a list and remove its duplicates.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  
the problem is the str(book) returns a string "book id: book title"  and each book has a unique id so the two books are not duplicates

Comment: If you count multiple copies of the same book as duplicates, then the unique ID doesn't matter and you should remove it before you add it to the list/set.

Answer (score -1):

Use a set instead of a string for results.  Sets don't allow duplicates, and it's faster to add elements to a set than to append to a string.  You can use `join` to create a string at the end if that's what you want.

```
def search(self, string):
    results = set()
    if len(string) >= 4:
        for book in self.collection:
            if (string.lower() in book_title.get_title().lower):
                results.add(str(book))
        return "".join(results)
```

Comment: but the thing is each book has a unique id..so even they are the same book, they have different ids

Comment: `book_title.get_title().lower` isn't gonna cut it.

Comment: and it will return the joined list of all results without space: hardly useful. You haven't tested that, it can't be (well, you trusted the OP code, but it's wrong)

Comment: cause the str(book) returns a string "book id: book title" so the two books are not duplicates in the set as their ids are different

Comment: @Vicky So instead of `str(book)`, add `book.get_title()` to the set.  If you care about preserving the id as well, then use a dict with book titles as keys and lists of ids as values.